# Calculating Time Variance within open & close times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as follows - please use `pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')` to copy into your editors.

```
    site    start_time  finish_time open_time   close_time  current_variance
1   22/08/2019 15:17    23/08/2019 17:37    09:00   17:00   1 days 02:20:00.000000000
1   12/08/2019 03:30    12/08/2019 08:30    09:00   17:00   0 days 05:00:00.000000000
1   19/08/2019 09:25    20/08/2019 09:15    09:00   17:00   0 days 23:50:00.000000000
2   21/08/2019 06:09    21/08/2019 08:19    09:00   17:00   0 days 02:10:00.000000000
2   16/08/2019 03:03    17/08/2019 10:07    09:00   17:00   1 days 07:04:00.000000000
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate the variance that fall within the site's open & close hours.

excluding any time outside of this which is set by the `open_time` and `close_time` columns.

Naturally, my real data has many different open and close times and probably many different variables to account for. The data comes from SAP so it comes into the site's when it's processed so it can come at any time. the finish_time is when it has been processed on site. I believe calculating with open and close times will solve *most*  of the issues here.

expected output

```
    site    start_time  finish_time open_time   close_time  actual_variance
1   22/08/2019 15:17    23/08/2019 17:37    09:00   17:00   0 Days 01:43:00
1   12/08/2019 03:30    12/08/2019 08:30    09:00   17:00   0 Days 00:00:00
1   19/08/2019 09:25    20/08/2019 09:15    09:00   17:00   0 Days 07:50:00
2   21/08/2019 06:09    21/08/2019 08:19    09:00   17:00   0 Days 00:00:00
2   16/08/2019 03:03    17/08/2019 10:07    09:00   17:00   0 Days 00:01:07
```

my own attempt has been a series of logical statements to see whether I should manually change the start or finish time but it quickly got very long, verbose and I wanted to know if anyone had a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we calculate the difference between the start time and the close time on the start day and clamp it between 0 and the maximum open time span. Then the difference between the open time and the finish time on the finish day, also clamping it to 0 ... open time span. Finally we need to add the number of full open time spans on all in-between days:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.width = 200
pd.options.display.max_columns = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'site': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2}, 'start_time': {0: '22/08/2019 15:17', 1: '12/08/2019 03:30', 2: '19/08/2019 09:25', 3: '21/08/2019 06:09', 4: '16/08/2019 03:03'}, 'finish_time': {0: '23/08/2019 17:37', 1: '12/08/2019 08:30', 2: '20/08/2019 09:15', 3: '21/08/2019 08:19', 4: '17/08/2019 10:07'}, 'open_time': {0: '09:00', 1: '09:00', 2: '09:00', 3: '09:00', 4: '09:00'}, 'close_time': {0: '17:00', 1: '17:00', 2: '17:00', 3: '17:00', 4: '17:00'}, 'current_variance': {0: '1 days 02:20:00.000000000', 1: '0 days 05:00:00.000000000', 2: '0 days 23:50:00.000000000', 3: '0 days 02:10:00.000000000', 4: '1 days 07:04:00.000000000'}})

# open time span
delta = pd.to_datetime(df.close_time) - pd.to_datetime(df.open_time)

# actual delta on start day
delta_start = df.apply(lambda r: pd.Timestamp.combine(pd.to_datetime(r.start_time), pd.to_datetime(r.close_time).time()), 1) - pd.to_datetime(df.start_time)
delta_start = delta_start.where(delta_start > pd.Timedelta(0), pd.Timedelta(0))
delta_start = delta_start.where(delta_start < delta, delta)

# actual delta on finish day
delta_finish = pd.to_datetime(df.finish_time) - df.apply(lambda r: pd.Timestamp.combine(pd.to_datetime(r.finish_time), pd.to_datetime(r.open_time).time()), 1)
delta_finish = delta_finish.where(delta_finish > pd.Timedelta(0), pd.Timedelta(0))
delta_finish = delta_finish.where(delta_finish < delta, delta)

# sum of start, finish and in-between days
df['actual_variance'] = delta_start + ((pd.to_datetime(df.finish_time).dt.date - pd.to_datetime(df.start_time).dt.date).dt.days - 1) * delta + delta_finish

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   site        start_time       finish_time open_time close_time           current_variance actual_variance
0     1  22/08/2019 15:17  23/08/2019 17:37     09:00      17:00  1 days 02:20:00.000000000        09:43:00
1     1  12/08/2019 03:30  12/08/2019 08:30     09:00      17:00  0 days 05:00:00.000000000        00:00:00
2     1  19/08/2019 09:25  20/08/2019 09:15     09:00      17:00  0 days 23:50:00.000000000        07:50:00
3     2  21/08/2019 06:09  21/08/2019 08:19     09:00      17:00  0 days 02:10:00.000000000        00:00:00
4     2  16/08/2019 03:03  17/08/2019 10:07     09:00      17:00  1 days 07:04:00.000000000        09:07:00
```

(in your expected output, you forget the day difference between start and finish days - for instance for the first row: we get 1:43 hrs on 22/08/19 plus another full 8 hrs on 23/08/19 - so it'll be 9:43 hrs instead of 1:43 hrs)

Comment: my man, you are a genius, thank you for the correction as well - going to test.

Comment: Thanks Mate worked like a charm I had to make a few adjustments but that's due to my data.

Comment: glad to have helped you